# Prove that $\left({1 \over 1-x}\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Prove that if $x\in [0, 1)$, then $\displaystyle \left({1 \over 1-x}\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$

I have a theorem which claims that

> **THEOREM:** If for some $x\in\mathbb R$ the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$ are absolutely convergent, then $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n\right) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n\right),$$ where $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}.$

I attempted the proof and the heart of the proof is extremely straightforward: $$\begin{align}\left({1 \over 1-x}\right)^2 & = \left({1 \over 1-x}\right)\left({1 \over 1-x}\right)\\ & = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty1x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty1x^n\right) \tag{Geometric Series}\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\left[\sum_{k=0}^n(1)(1)\right]x^n\right) \tag{Theorem}\\ &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[(n+1)x^n\right].\end{align}$$

However, is it necessary for the proof to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is absolutely convergent? I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing that. 
If I had to hazard a guess, I would say that since $x \in [0, 1)$, then $|x^n| = |x|^n = x^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x^n| = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ is convergent since it is a geometric series which implies the series is absolutely convergent. But is it valid to say two infinite series are "equal" like this?

Comment: You don't need that. Just multiply both sides of $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)x^n $$ by $(1-x)^2$ and notice a massive cancellation in the resulting RHS.

Comment: But, of course, convolution is a good way through. The Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is absolutely convergent as soon as $|x|<1$, so it is its square.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you have the multiplication theorem at hand, but you can easily prove the problem by differentiation. That is, try to differentiate both sides of the following identity $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^n}$$ and you'll get this $$\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{nx^{n-1}}$$ Since the first term of the summation is zero, you can change the index to get this $$\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(n+1)x^{n}}$$

Comment: This is a very good answer and it is how I first approached the problem. However, it is my fault that I probably should have specified that no such thing as differentiation has been mentioned in my textbook just yet. Therefore, we must use other tools to compute this (hence why I used a corollary to the Cauchy product).

Comment: I see. In order to prove the absolute convergence of the geometric series, you can start by deriving the finite sum formula, i.e., since $x\in[0,1)$ $$s_N=\sum_{n=0}^N{|x^n|}=\sum_{n=0}^N{x^n}=\frac{1-x^N}{1-x}$$ and then show its limit exists as $N$ approaches infinity.

Comment: although the answer itself is not as satisfactory as I'd like, I will choose this answer as correct for the comment listed above. :)

Comment: Thank you. And please consider this correction $s_N=\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to start from the right, the problem is simple since $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=x \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right)'+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\pars{1 \over 1 - x}^{2} & = \pars{1 - x}^{-2} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-2 \choose n}\pars{-x}^{n} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\braces{{-\bracks{-2} + n - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}}\pars{-x}^{n}
\\[5mm] & = 
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{n + 1 \choose n}x^{n} =
\bbx{\ds{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{n + 1}x^{n}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. The geometric series converges absolutey for $|x|<1$.

So, what is your problem ?

Comment: The issue I'm battling is listed at the very bottom of the post--is it valid to say that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x^n| = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ since $x\in[0,1)$, then $|x^n| = x^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$? It feels like sound logic, but my concern was that it felt like it's a very large jump in conclusions that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x^n|$ converges in the first place--so would it even make sense to say it equals a convergent series? That was my issue.

Comment: Yes you can! It's the same series exactly under a different name.